# Vue.js component with dynamic template (e.g. eventhandler)

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

lets say I made a compontent called test and inserted this into my html like so:

```
<test :data="foo"></test>
```

How can I achieve that the on-click attribute value changes into the property value 'data'?

```
Vue.component('test', {
props: ['data'],
template: '<div v-for="element in {{foo}}" >></div>'
});
```

---

Just to outline my expectations - this is what I am looking for:

```
<test :data="bar"></test>
<test :data="hello"></test>
```

renders to

```
<div v-for="element in bar" ></div>
<div v-for="element in hello" ></div>
```

BTW: Thanks to everyone participates here in SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent:

```
<test :data="foo" @onMyEvent="data=$event"></test>
```

Child component:

```
Vue.component('test', {
    props: ['data'],
    template: '<div @click="$emit(\'onMyEvent\', \'bar\')"></div>'
});
```

See [DOCS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events)

Based on your edits:

```
//Parent
<template>
    <div>
        <test :data="foo"></test>
        <test :data="bar"></test>
        <!-- or -->
        <test v-for="item in [foo, bar]" :data="item"></test>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Test from './Test.vue'
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                foo: ['foo-0', 'foo-1', 'foo-2', 'foo-3'],
                bar: ['bar-0', 'bar-1', 'bar-2', 'bar-3'],
            }
        },
        components: {
            test: Test
        }
    }
</script>
//Child component
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="element in data">{{ element }}</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: ['data'],
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to change the :data value on click.
I am searching for an approach to reuse :data when calling the template.
Please look at my edited expectations.

Comment: You cant use `v-for` in template root but this is allowed `template: '<div><div v-for="..." ></div><div>'` @j.mueller